# path in @CucumberOptions will work in Idea, or mvn verify, but not both

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have the following declaration before my test suite:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/", plugin = {"pretty",
    "json:target/cucumber.json"})
```

This works if I run the file from within Idea, however if I run `mvn verify` from the command line it does not work.

If I change it to

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "../src/test/resources/", plugin = {"pretty",
    "json:target/cucumber.json"})
```

...it works with `mvn verify` but not in Idea. Can I have my cake and eat it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your cukes and eat them too.  If you have a single Maven project with a standard layout and all of your Cucumber features are in `src/test/resources`, running the tests should work in both by omitting `features` entirely.

If you actually have your Cucumber features in a non-standard location, like in a parent Maven project, you can keep your command-line working with `../src/test/resources`, and change the working directory of your [Run/Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-application.html) to any directory that properly resolves the relative path.  You can change it for a specific configuration, or the default configuration so it will take effect for any configurations auto-generated by right-clicking.

Alternatively, you should also be able to use `src/test/resources` and set the [working directory](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#workingDirectory) of the `maven-surefire-plugin`, but it's better to make the IDE bend towards the command-line, not vice versa.